# pass socketio reference between layers in express4

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

I just started messing with websockets and express and I can't seem to get it to work with my current architecture.

I saw in another question to do the following before I declare my routes

```
//this goes prior to your route registration
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.io = io;
});
```

but I am not even sure how I can pass io to my app js to use the code snippet above.

i have my bin/www: I believe this was introduced in express4? the socket connects fine here

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('server:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * attach socket to express
 */
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);


io.sockets.on('connection', function() {
  console.log('!!!sockets io connected!!!');
})

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}
```

my app.js. this where I want to use the first code snippet right? but I am not sure how to pass 'io' to this file

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

/**
 * Route Imports
 */

var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

//THIS IS WHERE I WOULD PUT IT???? assuming I can pass IO into this??
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.io = io;
});

/**
 * Routes
 */
var router = require('./router')(app);

module.exports = app;
```

routers index.js

```
/**
 * The Index of Routes
 */

module.exports = function (app) {

  app.use('/test', require('./routes/test'));
}
```

and finally the route, im assuming once I get that first snippet in my app.js this would work since it will be attached to the req?

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
   //I WANT SOCKET TO JUST RESPOND WITH ANYTHING BUT I CANT GET 
   //AN INSTANCE OF IO IN HERE
   req.io.emit('test', 'hihi');
});

router.post('/', function (req, res) {
  test.save(function (err) {

    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        'message': 'error'
      });
    } else {
      // Log success
      console.log('Success');
      req.io.emit('test:added', test);
      res.status(201);
    }

  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

**NOTE: removed a lot of code for readability **

Answer (score 0):

Main module:

```
var app = express();
// ...
var server = http.createServer(app);
// ...
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// ...

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.io = io;
})

require('../app')(app); 
require('../routes')(app);
```

Your app module exposes `app` instance, so you can use it in your main module were you have access to `io`. Simple.

Comment: i get Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined. i think im supposed to do req io before i register my routes? which are done in app.js?

Comment: Yes, io first, then routes.

Comment: i know but that is done in var app = require('../app'); i would need to place that line in app.js vs bin/www. the code you showed above is telling me to stick it in bin/www which I can't do before registering routes

Comment: Then call `router(app)` in your main file below the io middleware. Or even better, create `var app = express()` in your main file and then pass the reference to `router` and  your old `app.js` or any other module that will set middlewares on you app instance.

Comment: Refactored the sample to show what I mean. It should give you a better idea what's happening as I'm creating the express app in the main file.